# How do I solve this congruency?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have this congruence relation:

2013 ≡ 1012 (mod m)

I am supposed to find all m in the natural system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$2013\equiv 1012\pmod m\implies m|(2013-1012)\implies m|1001$.

Thus all factors of $1001$ satisfy this.

Comment: I see, I was able to get this point. I was confused as to what to do next. Thanks.

Comment: That's why we are all here: to help and to be helped :)

Answer (score 3):

HINT: By definition $2013\equiv 1012\pmod m$ if and only if $m\mid 2013-1012$.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\ \ \ \rm mod\ m\!:\ 2013&\equiv& 1012\\ \rm \iff m\mid 2013&-&1012 = 1001 = 10^3\!+\!1 = (10\!+\!1)(10^2\!-\!10\!+\!1) = 11\cdot 91 = 11\cdot 7\cdot 13\end{eqnarray} $